# How do I start in CLI mode using a special boot parameter for the Live CD?

Tags: command-line, live-cd

Sometimes, I need to test some CLI programs without touching my real installation. For that purpose, I use a Virtual Machine running off a Live CD. Now, I don't need a full-blown user-friendly graphical interface, a CLI would suffice. I've earlier found a boot option to accomplish this, but I can't find it anymore.

- What is the boot option for skipping the graphical stuff and booting into a terminal?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/943696/boot-without-gui-from-live-cd for versions 15.04 and above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`quiet splash text`

All you need is `text` the other 2 should already be in the command line when you hit F6 at the start up screen.

Comment: Booting took -ages- edit: 7minutes to reach a command line  :D

Comment: it took me about ten seconds, my ISO is on my SSD and VirtualBox starts pretty quick on my i5 with 8GB RAM :D

Comment: I was using a cd ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer at https://askubuntu.com/a/943701/37574, this has changed as of 15.04 with the use of systemd.

So now instead of appending `text` to the kernel parameters, you now append the slightly less memorable `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`.

Once it boots you'll find yourself at a login prompt, where you can log in with 'ubuntu' and a blank password.