# live CD/pen drive boot option to go to TTY1 instead of Unity?

Tags: unity, boot, nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I start in CLI mode using a special boot parameter for the Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46733/how-do-i-start-in-cli-mode-using-a-special-boot-parameter-for-the-live-cd)

I am wondering if there is any boot option to prevent Precise from loading Unity and instead going straight to the terminal (because each time it tries to do so, it crashes).
From the command line my idea is to install the nvidia-current package to see if I can finally fix the problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do u mean loading the Lightdm ?

well while booting u can press CTRL + ALT + F1

and type in sudo lightdm stop

and then install the nvidia drivers!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a grub menu you should be able to press 'e' to edit the current boot option and type su to boot to single user mode where you will have a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

@Saversh
I finally installed the nvidia-current package, but now the screen goes black and the computer freezes... :S

@Jason
Thanks for the tip. I am curious because that might allow me to go to the terminal now that the drivers give me a black screen. Could you please tell me exactly what to add? Is it just "su to boot"?

Thanks both for your answers!

Comment: hmmm i got no idea now.....

Comment: Please do not use answers as a comment ;)