# Boot without GUI from live CD

Tags: boot, live-usb, text-mode

I am trying to boot Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as live system from the official ISO image without GUI. In previous versions, the `text` or `textonly` boot parameter could be added to the boot options. However, this possibility seems not working for the 16.04 release anymore.

Is there another option of booting without a GUI?

Comment: I know why it behaves like this (yes, unfortunately `systemd` is to blame for that, you would need to also change the default target - see the answers to https://askubuntu.com/q/16371/367990), but no idea how to change it from the live CD boot menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Booting into text mode in 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870221/booting-into-text-mode-in-16-04)

Comment: @krlmlr This question is different from the question referenced by you. This question is about booting from a Live CD/USB, while there is no option to manipulate the permanent OS configuration. The solutions shown in the referenced questions won't work for the Live CD/USB case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem why simply adding the `text` kernel parameter in GRUB to the live Ubuntu's boot options no longer works since 15.04 is actually our good old friend and enemy `systemd` once again. It ignores this option and just normally boots to its default target, which is `graphical.target` for a desktop GUI. For text mode, you would need `multi-user.target` though.

After a bit of research, I found out that it is indeed possible to specify the `systemd` target to load as kernel parameter at boot time in GRUB, it is:

```
systemd.unit=multi-user.target
```

Append that to the kernel boot options instead of `text` as you used to do in older releases and you should be fine.

Sources: [Arch Wiki: systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Change_default_target_to_boot_into) and ["Non-graphical boot with systemd" on Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164028/103151)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can confirm that this did the trick. I would rather prefer to have the `text' option again since this can be remembered more easily. But I am happy that there is at least another option of booting non-graphically. Thank you once again!